# Fastify with NextJS

Tags: fastify

I am looking for advice how to start fastify-cli with fastify-nextjs

I have tried to simple add code to suggested place, but it is not working.

```
'use strict'

const path = require('path')
const AutoLoad = require('fastify-autoload')

module.exports = function (fastify, opts, next) {
  // Place here your custom code!

  fastify.register(require('fastify-nextjs'))
      .after(() => {
        fastify.next('/hello')
      })

  // Do not touch the following lines

  // This loads all plugins defined in plugins
  // those should be support plugins that are reused
  // through your application
  fastify.register(AutoLoad, {
    dir: path.join(__dirname, 'plugins'),
    options: Object.assign({}, opts)
  })

  // This loads all plugins defined in services
  // define your routes in one of these
  fastify.register(AutoLoad, {
    dir: path.join(__dirname, 'services'),
    options: Object.assign({}, opts)
  })

  // Make sure to call next when done
  next()

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope this still help.

To register `nextjs` routes using the fastify client, you first must register the `@fastify/nextjs` plugin in a file inside the `plugin` folder.

**ESM**

```js
// plugin/next.js
import fp from "fastify-plugin";
import nextJs from "@fastify/nextjs";

export default fp(async (fastify, opts) => {
  fastify.register(nextJs);
});
```

**CommonJs**

```js
// plugin/next.js
const fp = require("fastify-plugin");
const nextJs = require("@fastify/nextjs");

module.exports = function fp(async (fastify, opts) {
  fastify.register(nextJs);
});
```

This will make available the `@fastify/nextjs` plugin decorators in all routes. (More about fastify plugin encapsulation on its [documentation](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Guides/Plugins-Guide/).)

Now you can render `nextjs` pages within fastify routes using the `@fastify/nextjs` reply decorator `nextRender`.

For example, if you have a nextjs page `pages/index.js`, you could render it like this:

**ESM**

```js
// plugin/root.js

const root = async (fastify, opts) => {
  fastify.get("/", async function (request, reply) {
    return reply.nextRender("/");
  });

  // There is no link between fastify routes and nextjs routes.
  // So you can render any nextjs page on any fastity route.
  // Here the nextjs page pages/index.js is available also at the 
  // /app fastify route
  fastify.get("/app", async function (request, reply) {
    return reply.nextRender("/");
  });
};

export default root;
```

**CommonJs**

```js
// plugin/root.js

module.exports = async function root(fastify, opts) {
  fastify.get("/", async function (request, reply) {
    return reply.nextRender("/");
  });

  // There is no link between fastify routes and nextjs routes.
  // So you can render any nextjs page on any fastity route.
  // Here the nextjs page pages/index.js is available also at the 
  // /app fastify route
  fastify.get("/app", async function (request, reply) {
    return reply.nextRender("/");
  });
};
```

Look at this [post](https://wladimirguerra.medium.com/fastify-next-js-and-typescript-68ba4e12ca51) if you plan to code with Typescript.

Comment: does one need to trigger next js build script before running the server or fastify-nextjs takes care of that, especially if ts was used?

Comment: Hi @Curtis `fastify-nextjs` takes care of that.